# How to validate XML file with Schematron if Schematron .sch file is given

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-validation, schematron

I want to validate XML file against Schematron using saxon9ee.jar/saxon9he.jar.
Schemafile .sch calling .xsl file:

```
<xsl:include href="library_001.xsl"/>
```

How to use saxon jar using command line?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955568/how-to-perform-schematron-validation-using-saxon-java-library-command-line-tool (but not sure)

Comment: First question: are you using the XSLT2 reference implementation of Schematron found here? http://www.schematron.com/implementation.html

Comment: Yes. I'm using XSLT2.