# Validating xml file against schematron (.sch) in .Net (Saxon)

Tags: saxon, schematron

I need to validate an XML file against Schematron (.sch file). I read that Saxon can do it. How can I use Schematron file directly as all the sample uses XSLT, not the Schematron file?

Answer (score 0):

There are Schematron processors that use Saxon "underneath the hood", but Saxon itself does not have any schematron capability.

Comment: As per my understanding, the Schematron needs to be converted to XSL and that XSL will be used to validate the document. Can you tell me how to achieve this in Saxon.Net? I have ISO Schematron file.  Can we also use XSD as a file for validation? as sometimes we need multiple files to validate a single document.

Comment: I have found a solution and its working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059562/using-saxon-9-5-nuget-with-schematron